# Python nested type check in runtime without external packages

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there some type checking API from python3.5 typing that I can use to check nested types in runtime.
For example:

```
from typing import List
check_type([1,2,3], List[int]) # True
check_type([1,2,''], List[int]) # False
```

This is only example (it can be 3 or more levels nested, have List, Tuple, Dict)

Comment: No but you can implement it pretty easily: `def check_type(li, inner_type): return isinstance(li, list) and all(isinstance(obj, inner_type) for obj in li)`

Comment: maybe this helps: http://mypy-lang.org/? or check out any of the other references at the bottom of the [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) built-in function like below:

```
def check_type(iterable, tp):
    return all(isinstance(item, tp) for item in iterable)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> check_type([1, 2, 3], int)
True
>>>
>>> check_type([1, 2, ''], int)
False
```

Comment: [`isinstance` is recommend over `type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) - _"The `isinstance()` built-in function is recommended for testing the type of an object, because it takes subclasses into account."_.

Comment: sorry, iterable is only example, just for simplify the question. In real structure can be complex, so I thought I can call something without manual falling to the bottom of structure

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks! I updated my answer.

Comment: @user3479125 How does you data structure look like?